# Are method parameters thread safe?

Tags: c#

```
public void Remove(T item)
{
    locker.EnterWriteLock();        
    try
    {
        list.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

The above is a method on an instance class.  Say the instance is `myObject`.
With regard to the above fragment, my question is this:

Thread one calls `myObject.Remove(A)`.
Thread one executes `locker.EnterWriteLock()`.

Thread two calls `myObject.Remove(B)`.

Thread one enters the try block and executes `list.Remove()`.

What is the value of `item` at this point?  i.e. is `list.Remove()` going to be called with A or B as a parameter?

Comment: What is they type of the `locker` variable?

Comment: This question could have been easily answered by debugging and checking. The question of _why_ to the answer you find out would have been better.

Comment: @DaveZych It's non-trivial to effectively debug code and force certain race conditions in a mutithreaded environment.  Possible, just...difficult.

Comment: Debugging or analyzing two concurrent threads turns out to be not that easy. How would you arrange the desired timing without throwing more synchronization primitives at it? I am aware that there are some specialized tools but I do not believe they are in widespread use.

Comment: Dave you are right. but if I get B I am going to ask how to get A, and if I get A I'm going to ask why......... so either which way.... and as others have mentioned its difficult to do.

Comment: @DanielBrückner It's not *that* hard, and you can't (and shouldn't) change the code.  In visual studio you can pause all threads, then choose a thread and execute lines of code one by one until you get to a certain point, then switch to another thread and have it execute code line by line (or continuously until you hit a breakpoint).  It's just tedious and annoying, especially if you want to constantly get to the same "state" time after time.

Comment: You are right, didn't think about that (because I luckily never had to do that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each thread has their own call stack, and method arguments are stored on that stack.  The stack is not shared between threads.

In thread one's stack there is a line indicating that `Remove` is being called and that contains either "A" or a reference to "A" (depending on whether it's a value or reference type).

When thread two enters the method it has it's own call stack (thread 1's stack is unused while thread two is running)  which has a line indicating the start of `Remove` with item "B".  Then that thread is suspended, it's call stack is unused, and we go back to thread 1, where item "A" is what's on the call stack.

At some point in the future thread two will be reactivated and will have item "B" on it's call stack.

Comment: Yes, each call of `Remove` sort of creates a new "instance" of `Remove`.

Answer (score 1):

Method arguments are allocated on the stack of the thread calling the method. Therefore every thread has its own arguments and they do not influence each other.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that what you should be locking on here is the `list` variable. You are calling the `Remove` method on it and if this `list` variable is some type which is not thread safe such as `List<T>` for example you could get into trouble if this method is invoked concurrently from multiple threads on the same instance of `myObject` (which is where your `list` field lives). As far as the argument of the method are concerned, it's hard to talk about any thread safety for them within the context of the method.

Comment: Understood. My question is - by the time I actually call Remove on the list, will I be calling it with A or B?

Comment: Given that we have no indication what the scope of `locker` is we couldn't really comment on this.  He may or may not be locking at the appropriate scope, but that's not really relevant to his question; it's much more basic than that.

Comment: You will be calling it with whatever the value of the parameter is. So for example if you called the method with A then A will be passed to the remove method. Method arguments live on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

.Net does not provide any inherit locking on parameters. However, `list.Remove(item)` does not modify `item` (assuming it is the standard `System.Collections` or `System.Collections.Generic` implementation) and invoking the same method twice with different arguments creates two copies of `item` (one in each method call), not one.

Instead, I would lock list since the instance methods on most classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

Thread 2 will be waiting at `locker.EnterWriteLock();` for thread 1 to execute `locker.ExitWriteLock();`

So thread 2 just cannot access `list` before thread 1 call `locker.ExitWriteLock();`

If you worry about parameter `item`, be sure that it passed through stack and each thread has its own one, so `item` really cannot be "substituted" by another thread...

So the answer is: if thread 1 called `locker.EnterWriteLock();` before thread 2, `A` will be removed before `B`.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `item` will be the value of the `A` parameter.

Only once the line `locker.ExitWriteLock` has executed will the block will be available to thread one.